Trying to understand behavior of `_field_defaults` of `namedtuple` in Python 3.9
I am new to Python's namedtuple, particularly, _field_defaults.
According to Python 3.12.3 official doc,

some namedtuple._field_defaults
Dictionary mapping field names to default values.

Would someone explain the odd behavior of the following code snippet?
Apparently, the one provided by Copilot generates the error code listed below.

Text-based code snippet from above.
from collections import namedtuple

# Define the namedtuple
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name age')

# Set default values
Person._field_defaults['name'] = 'John'
Person._field_defaults['age'] = 30

# Create a namedtuple with default values
person1 = Person()

# Create a namedtuple with a different name
person2 = Person(name='Alice')

print(person1)  # Outputs: Person(name='John', age=30)
print(person2)  # Outputs: Person(name='Alice', age=30)

The following error was produced.
>>> person1 = Person()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'age'

>>> Person=namedtuple('Person', ['name', 'age'], defaults=['default_name', 0])
>>> p = Person()
>>> p
Person(name='default_name', age=0)
>>> p._field_defaults
{'name': 'default_name', 'age': 0}
>>> p._field_defaults['age'] = 100
>>> p = Person()
>>> p
Person(name='default_name', age=0)
>>>

Observed from the code snippet above, p._field_defaults['age'] = 100 changed the dictionary, but the default construction of Person was not updated.

Please ask only one question per question.

Also post code/text as text not an image that can't be copied/pasted/executed.

Do not trust Copilot. It's generative AI. It will make up things that sound vaguely like they could be right.

@user2357112 Yep, yep. I am using Copilot to expedite the learning process. I am verifying each result. Thank you for pointing that out.

Side note: named tuples aren't that interesting now that we have dataclasses.

"Why p._field_defaults['age'] = 100 changed the dictionary, but the default construction of Person was not updated?" why do you believe it should be updated? Nothing in the documentation implies that should happen.

@101 While there's overlap, there are still valid uses for named tuples (namely, they can be used where a tuple is expected).

You'll find the implementation at collections.__init__.py. namedtuple creates new types. In the current implementation (3.13), defaults are actually a tuple on the type's __new__ method. _field_names is informational only. This is because..., well, I don't know. Things that start with "_" are implementation details that could change at any time. The default parameter was added in python 3.7 and its implementation may have changed over time. You really shouldn't depend on how it works on any given release (like the codepilot snippet did).
As for the order of defaults, the documentation states

Since fields with a default value must come after any fields without a
default, the defaults are applied to the rightmost parameters.

This is how a python function is called, so namedtuple has to play the game.

namedtuple uses (for better or worse) _-prefixed names for its public interface: "To prevent conflicts with field names, the method and attribute names start with an underscore."

@chepner Thx. TIL.
I am curious about the convention in Python, should I be using any public interface that starts with an underscore? I thought standard libraries should be fairly "standard".

Usually, a leading underscore specifically means it is not part of the public interface. In the case of namedtuple, they chose to break from that convention so that one could define something like, for example, Car = namedtuple('Car', 'make', 'model', 'year') without conflicting with the _make method. (That is, the author allowed common methods to take a backseat--no car pun intended--to field names chosen by the user.) Documentation trumps convention, though, so even though _make et al. look private, they are part of the public interface.
